# upload file to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload file to my database but every attempt keeps giving me an `Error Query Failed`.

My code is below:

```html
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label> Name of Institution/ School</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="institution">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Graduating Year</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="graduate">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"></div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Upload Document</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
    <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="upload" value="upload" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  
</form>

<?php

$institution =  $_POST['institution'];
$graduate =  $_POST['graduate'];
$userid = '12';

if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}


//include 'library/config.php';
include('../config/hr_config.php');

$query = "INSERT INTO education (user_id, institution, graduate, name, size, type, content ) ".
"VALUES ('$userid', '$institution', '$graduate','$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";

mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
//include 'library/closedb.php';

echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
}
?>
```

It keeps giving error, anyone can help me look into this?

Comment: Instead of using a fixed error message, try switching to `die(mysql_error())`, and let the database tell you what the error is. Even better - don't use a deprecated database API; switch to one that lets you use prepared statements.

Comment: After doing that, i got this error. "Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Comment: You're not connecting to the database properly. Check your connection statement and the credentials you're using.

Comment: Your data content field in your database must be a `blob` field type to store file data